# Windows 8 PID4 Constantly Writing to "wfpdiag.etl"

Tags: windows, hard-drive

The C: drive on my Windows 8 machine is clicking away at 1 second intervals, writing to `wfpdiag.etl`. I'd like to find out why.

Looking at the Resource Monitor and the Sysinternals Process Explorer, I see that it's PID 4, "System" that is doing the disk access. It's writing about 32K (1 write) every second.

Here is the constant disk access:
[image]

And here is the periodic writing.
[image]

The "Writes" number increments once a second. Performance Monitor tells me it's writing to a file called wpdiag.etl, which I understand to be related to the Windows Firewall. Is there any way I can disable the writing to this file?

Comment: The fact that System is doing what you say, is pretty normal.  The fact that your drive is audibly clicking is not (presuming it's actually a louder than normal clicking. :) ).  Have you checked the disk for defects using the manufacturer's utilities yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hard drive clicking, but no errors](http://superuser.com/questions/261670/hard-drive-clicking-but-no-errors) also see [Faulty hard-drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/79039/faulty-hard-drive) and [New Laptop hard drive is clicking](http://superuser.com/questions/181318/new-laptop-hard-drive-is-clicking)

Comment: It is not a faulty hard drive. It is a file being written to. I'd like to get rid of the writing to the file.

Comment: same problem, it's very annoying.
btw how did you know exact file name? (wfpdiag.etl)
I couldn't find where to look at...

Comment: i have no such file, but my System process is constantly writing something

Comment: Are you running IPSec tunnels or performing any diagnostic logging of IP traffic?

Answer (score 3):

How's your Japanese: http://blog.livedoor.jp/nichepcgamer/archives/1042899759.html?
Leads to a slightly helpful KB entry:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3044882

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You have a custom networking application installed on your server.
> - The application captures lots of traffic on the wire.
> - The server may be using a DHCP-assigned IP address.
>
> In this scenario, a large volume of disk I/O may be generated when writes are made to the C:\Windows\System32\wfp\wfpdiag.etl log.
>   This behavior is by design. When the Port Scanning Prevention Filter is triggered, this typically means that there is no process listening on the port. (For security reasons, WFP blocks process listening.) When a connection is tried on a port where there is no listener, WFP recognizes the packet as if it were coming from a port scanner and therefore silently drops the connection.
>   If there had been a listener, and the communication was instead blocked because of either malformed packets or authentication, the dropped event would be listed as “DROP” (not silent), and WFP logging would indicate a different filter ID and name.
>   This filter is built in to the Windows Firewall and Advanced Security (WFAS). It is included in Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and later versions of Windows.

The workaround listed lets you guess the registry key, where you are supposed to add dword `CollectNetEvents` with a value of `0` under.

Fortunately the blogpost hints at netsh, you can dump an .xml of wfpdiag.etl with
`netsh wfp show netevents` and
disable it with
`netsh wfp set options netevents=off` from an elevated prompt, which also creates the aforementioned registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Options`

> Note By disabling WFP logging, this only stops the logging of WFP activity in wfpdiag.etl. The Port Scanning Prevention Filter continues to work normally.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer, running this alone `netsh wfp set options netevents=off ` appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have software called Windows7FirewallControl from Sphinx? Software site: http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/index.html

Some have reported that it was responsible for this write pattern: http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/68952-wfpdiag-etl-what.html Uninstalling or disabling it stopped the constant write activity to that file.

Comment: No, I haven't installed any firewall or other network analysis or antivirus programs. This is basically a new Windows 8 install.